# Array - Pegar names: Url e Caption

Tags: php

Eu tenho inputs dinamicos com names `my_image[url]` e `my_image[caption]`

```
<input name="my_image[url]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $imgurl['url'];?>"/>
<input name="my_image[caption]" type="text" value="<?php echo $imgurl['caption'];?>">
```

Mesmo inserido diversas imagens e captions dinamicamente, dentro do isset o `$ _POST ['my_image']` esta capturando apenas 1 imagem e 1 caption:

```
if (isset($_POST['my_image'])){ 
    update_option('imagens_inicio',array($_POST['my_image']);
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST['my_image']);echo '</pre>';
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(96) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/4e07dd2bd752b989e9b4687129982977.jpg"
    ["caption"]=>
    string(0) "test text"
  }
}
```

Como faço para o array ser criado em uma sequencia continua:

```
url[]
caption[]
url[]
caption[]
```

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Acredito que o nome do campo deverá seguir o formato `my_image[0][url]` e `my_image[0][caption]`, incrementando o valor de 0 a cada campo dinâmico inserido na página.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não funcionou, fiz a pergunta em ingles tbm, mas não entendi bem a solução proposta veja: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989305/how-do-i-capture-all-input-names-of-post-my-image/45989792#45989792)

Comment: Na minha opinião a solução apresentada no SOen é boa, renomeando os inputs para `url[]` e `caption[]`, que cria dois arrays independentes com a numeração sequencial automática. Naturalmente irá alterar a forma como os lê, como foi indicado nessa resposta

Comment: @Isac ah tah entendi agora a logica da resposta dele, mas não entendi essa parte: `($url, $caption) { return compact('url', 'caption');` as variaveis `$url` e `$caption` são subentendidas que se refere ao post url e post caption? 'url' e 'caption' nas aspas simples tbm fica subentendido isso?

Comment: Referem-se aos parâmetros do `array_map`. Ele usa a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) do php que no exemplo dele pega em dois arrays, o `, $_POST['url'], $_POST['caption'])` e os interliga à custa da função [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php). O compact recebe duas strings com o nome das variáveis a colocar num novo array.

Comment: Certo entendi, mas o `var_dump($data);` esta retornando `null`

Comment: finalmente consegui!  Coloquei em variaveis o  `$_POST['url'];` e `$_POST['caption'];` pois diretamente no `array_map` não estava funcionando. muito obrigada @Isac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com ajuda no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989305/how-do-i-capture-all-input-names-of-post-my-image), na pergunta que fiz la também, e ajuda do @Isac aqui do SOpt consegui resolver:

```
 if (isset($_POST['url'])){ 

          $url = $_POST['url'];
          $caption = $_POST['caption'];

          $data = array_map(function ($url, $caption) {
                return compact('url', 'caption');
           }, $url, $caption);

           update_option('imagens_inicio',$data);

    }
```